# Error copyng a string - ASM

Tags: string, assembly, masm, x86

I'm studying a assembly book and, well, the program copy the string contained in origen to destino. The program compile without errors, but when I execute it, Windows say: "The program needs to close".

I'm programming IA-32 assembly, and compiling with Qeditor.

This is the code:

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

.data
origen BYTE  "Esta es la cadena de origen",0 ; "This is the source string",0
destino BYTE  SIZEOF origen DUP(0)

.code

start:
mov  esi,0 ; index register
mov  ecx,SIZEOF origen ; loop counter

L1:
    mov al,origen[esi] ; obtain a character from origen
    mov destino[esi],al ; store character in destino
    inc esi ; move to next character
    loop L1 ; repeat the process for all characters contained in the string

END start
```

I've tried to debug it, but when finish the loop, the program have access error. I don't  understand why.
Please, help.
Debugging: http://www.subirimagenes.com/otros-captura1-8802120.html

Thank you.

==========

## SOLUTION

I edited the code a bit, but is the same.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include     \masm32\include\masm32.inc

includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib  \masm32\lib\masm32.lib ; StdIn, StdOut

.data
origen BYTE  "Hello world.",0
destino BYTE  SIZEOF origen DUP(0)

.code
main PROC
    mov  esi,0 ; registro í­ndice
    mov  ecx,LENGTHOF origen ; ECX = 12 veces


bucle:
    mov al,[origen + esi]
    mov [destino + esi],al
    add esi,TYPE origen
    loop bucle

    ; Wheen loop finish, execute this:
    invoke StdOut, OFFSET destino ; print
    invoke ExitProcess, 0 ; exit
main ENDP
END main
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to terminate the program after the loop exits.  It must explicitly call the "exit program" system call, or return to the caller, or whatever it is supposed to do when it ends.

As written, it just keeps executing memory beyond the `loop` instruction doing whatever the bytes that happen to be there instruct.  That is surely not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The loop never ends.
EDIT: Actually it ends.

Here is how you could do :

```
mov  esi,0 ; index register
mov  ecx,SIZEOF origen ; loop counter

L1:
    mov al,origen[esi] ; obtain a character from origen
    mov destino[esi],al ; store character in destino
    inc esi ; move to next character
    cmp esi, ecx ; set flags
    jne L1 ; repeat the process for all characters contained in the string if index != size

END start
```

Comment: That does not appear to  be the problem.  The `loop` instruction decrements ecx.  If it is not zero or below (I forget which), it jumps to the label.

Comment: The 'loop' will check 'ecx' before looping. The loop will terminate normally, but the behave after the loop is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I didn't call a exit.
Well, I've programmed a exit, but I want execute a print (StdOut) when finish the loop. **How I cando this?** Actually the program don't print the string because no execute StdOut.

**Cyril Fougeray**: With this I have the same problem, and LOOP have a condicition (ECX).

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include     \masm32\include\windows.inc
include     \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include     \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib  \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib  \masm32\lib\masm32.lib ; StdIn, StdOut

.data
origen BYTE  "Esta es la cadena de origen",0
destino BYTE  SIZEOF origen DUP(0)

.code
start:
    mov  esi,0
    mov  ecx,SIZEOF origen
    jmp L1
    invoke StdOut, OFFSET destino
    invoke ExitProcess, 0

L1:
    mov al,origen[esi]
    mov destino[esi],al
    inc esi
    loop L1


END start
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving string is frequently used operation, hence it's got its own machine instruction in x86 assembly:

```
start:
    mov esi,OFFSET origen
    mov edi,OFFSET destino
    mov ecx,SIZEOF destino
    cld 
    rep movsb
    ret
```

Comment: Thank you very much :), but I need do this with the loop instruction. I need: copy string, print string and exit. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should get rid of *spaghetti* **jmp L1**, otherwise your process never gets to **invoke StdOut** after the loop has finished:

```
.data
    origen BYTE  "Esta es la cadena de origen",0
    destino BYTE  SIZEOF origen DUP(0)
    BytesWritten DWORD 0
.code
start:
    mov  esi,0
    mov  ecx,SIZEOF origen
L1:
    mov al,origen[esi]
    mov destino[esi],al
    inc esi
    loop L1
    invoke StdOut, OFFSET destino
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
```

If invoking MASM's macro **StdOut** still gives no output, see also 
[masm32 invoking stdout gives no output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144764/masm32-invoking-stdout-gives-no-output)
In Windows I prefer native method of writing to standard output:

```
  invoke GetStdHandle,STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ; get standard output handle to EAX
  invoke WriteFile,EAX,OFFSET destino, SIZEOF origen,OFFSET BytesWritten,0 ; write destino to StdOut
```

For more info about theese Windows functions see 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910675.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I saw this question 8 days ago and had assumed you had resolved it. Essentially Wally was correct at the beginning.

Your app is continuing to process junk code after your code is executed as it is not told when to stop = Get yourself a good disassembler. As you are not using the stack and it remains balanced you simply need to provide a 'retn' after your code.

Using Windows libraries (you posted under MASM) you would usually issue an "invoke ExitProcess," contained in kernel32.

The following will work as expected (but will not output anything as you don't specify you need to):

```
.386
.MODEL flat, stdcall
OPTION CASEMAP:NONE 

.data
origen db "Esta es la cadena de origen",0 ; Source string zero terminated
destino db SIZEOF origen dup(0) ;Buffer zero initialised

.code

Start:

xor esi,esi ;esi = 00000000
xor eax,eax ;eax = 00000000
mov ecx,sizeof origen ;loop counter

L1:
mov al,origen[esi] ;get a byte from esi (character from 'origen')
mov destino[esi],al ;store byte (character) in 'destino'
inc esi ;move to next byte (character)
loop L1

retn ;magic instruction!

End Start
```